# Counting the Number of Modifications in a Document Library

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, calculated-column-formula

This seems easy, but having a hard time figuring this issue out.  I want to count the number of modifications that occur on a line item in a document library.  I was thinking I can accomplish by turning on versioning.  But I will not be able to show this as a column option.  Is there a way to show the number of times a line item/document has been modified in a column?  I was thinking of creating a calculated COUNT column.  But this may not be the best approach.  Does anyone know how to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

1. Enable Versioning. Create only Major Versions.
2. Modify the view. Add **Version** column to the view

The **Version** column will now show the count of modifications done on the item.